# Customizer – Allow user editor to change website title and tagline

Tags: user-roles, theme-customizer

In the customizer you may change the site title and tagline (input fields) under »Site title & tagline« as an admin. When logged in as an editor the menu item is visible but when clicking on it both options are not available.

How is it possible to grand editors permission to edit title and tagline in the customizer?

Answer (score 1):

Use a plugin like User Role Editor to add the 'manage_options' capability to the specific users or their role. Of course, this will allow them to manage *all* options.

Or add PHP code like this:

```
$wp_customize->get_setting( 'title_tagline' )->capability = 'edit_others_posts';
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities